# Creating a datatable based on textbox and checkbox values C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to create a `DataTable` in `C#`.  Right now my `ascx` page has two `TextBoxes`.  One for student ID `txtStudentID` and one for student name `txtStudentName`.  It also has a `CheckBox` list on it (ckbxPF) that has Pass or Fail.  I need to create a `DataTable` with these values based on user input and then have the table returned.

Also, if anyone knows how to access those values in a different `class` that would be great!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!
-Tom

Comment: Show what you have and ask a specific question based on your code.

Comment: I have two  textboxes on a Web Control.  These text boxes will have user input and I need to capture that input in a datatable.  I need to use values that are stored in this datatable in a different class of my project.  I haven't started to code yet.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that i don't understand the question, but ok, here's one way to create the DataTable:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("StudentID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("StudenName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Passed", typeof(bool));

int studentID = int.Parse(txtStudentID.Text);
String studentName = txtStudentName.Text;
bool passed = ckbxPF.SelectedIndex == 0; // assuming that "passed" is the first item

table.Rows.Add(studentID, studentName, passed);
```

You can pass this `DataTable` for example by returning it from a method in the class or - if you have a reference to that class - via properties, for example:

```
// somewhere in Class2
DataTable table = class1.Table;

//in Class1, initialize this table from where you want
public DataTable Table { get; set;}
```

Comment: Now I just need to use two of those values in a different class than where the datatable is created.  For example, I need to print the following line: "StudentName" (textbox value) "Passed" (checkbox).  Thanks again!

Comment: @TomBlouise: When you have a reference to the DataTable in the different class (via property,Session,(static) method,constructor,...), you just need to read the first row(since there is just one row in the table) to get your values. `string studentName = table.Rows[0].Field<String>("StudentName");`.